# Set property to element

Tags: wpf, xaml

I searched and testet alot but i don't get it. How is it possible to set the property of one object to a element which is defined in xaml? I tried it with bindings but it won't work.

**Xaml-sample:**

```
<RadioButton Content="Settings" Height="Auto" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Padding="5" IsChecked="True" Checked="MenuCheckbox_Checked" />
<p:SettingsPage x:Name="SettingsPage" />
```

In the example i want to set the `Tag` property of the `RadioButton` to the object reference of the `SettingsPage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx)?

```
<RadioButton Tag="{x:Reference SettingsPage}" ...>
```

Comment: ... Head -> Desk!! I searched for a half hour and the solution is so easy...can't belive it! Is there any way to use this feature in the designer?

Comment: @FelixK.: I don't know, i despise designers and don't want anything to do with them. By the way, an `ElementName` binding should do as well: `{Binding ElementName=SettingsPage}`, unless there are weird things going on with the namescopes (i.e. the proximity shown in your code above is not actually the case).

Comment: I noticed that the designer is not working anymore when using `x:Reference`. Edit: Now it works. Don't know why but it works. thanks.

Comment: @FelixK.: Well, `ElementName` is not too smart, if you interested in the reason why it does not bind [check the output window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx). If you wrap the `x:Reference` in a binding the designer maybe won't notice, i.e. `{Binding Source={x:Reference SettingsPage}}`

Comment: He does, however the `Binding` way works. It seems to me that i had a missing character in the binding target.